# Ajax forms in pages

Tags: ajax

I am trying to code Drupal Ajax forms in Drupal pages (Drupal Content type: Basic page). However, it seems like the callback does not work, because when I remove the callback function nothing changes, and when I paste it back nothing changes.

Here is my code:

```
$the_ajax3_form = drupal_get_form('ajax_example_simplestt');
print drupal_render($the_ajax3_form);

function ajax_example_simplestt($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();
  $form['changethis'] = array(
    '#title' => t("Choose something and explain why"),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(
      'one' => 'one',
      'two' => 'two',
      'three' => 'three',
    ),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_simplestt_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div',
    ),
  );

  $form['replace_textfield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_textfield_div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  if (!empty($form_state['values']['changethis'])) {
    $form['replace_textfield']['#description'] = t("Say why you chose '@value'", array('@value' => $form_state['values']['changethis']));
  }
  return $form;
}

function ajax_example_simplestt_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['replace_textfield'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX function callback is misspelled. This would be why it is not getting called.

Change `ajax_example_simplest_callback` to `ajax_example_simplestt_callback`.

Whichever spelling is correct, simplest or simplestt... Not knowing your context I do not know which it should be. But yeah, the function in the #ajax property is not defined in the context of this question.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have edited the code and corrected the misspelled function for ajax callback but i till have the same problem. Nothing changes. I also cleared the cache and refreshed the page, nothing. Can try to run the code if you are able.

Comment: The next thing to do would be to put an exit() (not recommended), devel (for dpm or dsm), or use a debugger like xdebug (highly recommended) to step through the code, and ensure that the callback is being hit.

Comment: Hi Kevin, i have debugged the form using devel and everything is okay. However, i used firebug to debug the response to the server and realised that the function does not return data. More help will be appreciated...

Comment: Since this looks like the same example given in the examples module, I would assume that it is working (given no typos) and more in how it is being shown on the page. What is the result if you move this to being a menu item callback instead of the first two lines of code?

Comment: Hi Kevin, let me work on that...ill get back to you soon.

Comment: Hi Kevin, i moved my form to menu item (module) and everything was okay. I hope Drupal can address this: make ajax available in drupal content types. However, since i needed the form in my content types, i used: $the_ajax3_form = drupal_get_form('ajax_example_simplestt');
print drupal_render($the_ajax3_form); to callback the form in my content type (the form remained as a menu item), and its now working fine so far. Thank you.

Comment: It does support it, you can alter a node CRUD form and add AJAX to it as long as you handle everything correctly.